# OSS implementation of Google app engine?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, cloud

After Google pioneered map-reduce the community came out with Hadoop, is there a OSS Google AppEngine project? Or, put another way: What is the best off the shelf python or java cloud software?

Specifically I'm looking for something that I could host on my own and have some sort of auto-scale feature (more frequently used apps would be replicated or something).

Is this a pipe dream? or is there something out there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by having an OSS version of Google app engine, but [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/) is an open source framework for running Google app engine apps. You'll have to provide your own cloud, however.

I think with the right technical expertise and hardware you could host this on your own. Not so sure about auto-scaling, but I'm sure there's a programmatic solution to that.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/), which is similar to AppScale.  TyphoonAE does a better job of keeping current with GAE/Python then AppScale does.

Both can easily be deployed to Amazon EC2.